# how to avoid variable expansion for a bash for loop in define makefile

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

Usually, I use foreach call in a makefile. Notwithstanding, I wanted to try different approaches.
For that, I have created the code bellow.

I am using GNU Make 3.81
I have replaced the eval by info to understand what is happening.
I cannot avoid both the call and the eval expansion to keep the $file

I mean, when I open the file I am getting:
"for file in *.v; do echo ; echo ; done;  > trial.sh;"

```
define create_area
$(1): $(2)
    mkdir -p $$(@D); \
    cp -nLr -v $(2)/* $$(@D); \
    cd $$(@D); \
    for file in *.v; do echo $$(file); \
    done; \
    " > trial.sh;

$(foreach a,$(A1) $(A2),\
$(foreach b,$(B1),\
$(eval $(call create_area,$(a),$(b)))))
```

Thank you in advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost there.

If you run the loop in a shell, you must precede the variable name with '$' so that it will be expanded.

If you put that command in a makefile recipe, to prevent Make from expanding the variable name too soon (when the variable has not yet been given a value) you must precede ("escape") that '$' with another '$'.

If you put that recipe in a definition which you will expand with `call`, you must double *each* of them:

```
for file in *.v; do echo $$$$file; done
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It worked, as expected and I am feeling a bit dumb.
Just one more question. 
For sure I have tried $$($$(file)), somehow it made sense in my mind. But this does not work.  Is this because, since the dollar signs are not together it interprets as two variables extentions?

Thank you in advance,

Comment: Shouldn't it be `$$$$file`, instead of `$$($$(file))` or `$$$$(file)`? It is a shell variable, not a make variable.

Comment: yes, it should be $$$$file. Otherwise, the shell thinks it is trying to execute the command file.

Comment: @RenaudPacalet: You're right, thank you, I'll edit.